# Javascript Regex Validation for numbers seperated by # sign and repetead at max 4 times

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I require a Regex for answers separated by `#`. Unfortunately I couldn't find a proper way to do this. Answers should be in the range 1 to 5.

Here is my requirements:

- Input can be empty
- Input can include single number 1 to 5 after that before every new number it should be separated by `#`.
- Input length can be 9 at max.
- Input can not end with # sign.

Some valid Examples:

```
1
3#4
1#5#4
1#2#3#4
1#2#3#4#5
```

Some invalid Examples:

```
3# // can not end with #
1#2#3#4#5#1 // length more than 9
6 // only numbers 1 to 5
```

I would appreciate any help as I am new to this.

I wrote some examples on top I can't understand how to build regex at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following expression:

```
/^(?:[1-5](?:#[1-5]){0,4})?$/
```

1. Start of line `^`
2. Optional (`?`), non-matching group (`?:`)

   1. Must start with a `[1-5]`
   2. Followed by `0 to 4` occurances of

      1. `#` and
      2. `[1-5]`
3. End of line `$`

```js
const
  validValues   = ['', '3#4','1#5#4','1#2#3#4','1#2#3#4#5'],
  invalidValues = ['3#','1#2#3#4#5#1','6'];

const isValid = (str) => /^(?:[1-5](?:#[1-5]){0,4})?$/.test(str);

// Valid tests
console.log(validValues.every(isValid));

// Invalid tests
console.log(!invalidValues.some(isValid));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland I updated based on this information.

Comment: I'm a regex dummy thanks for the answer it is working

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: https://regexr.com/79au1

The regex: `[1-5](#[1-5]){0,4}`

- `[1-5]` match any number between 1 and 5
- `#` match character `#`
- `(...){n,m}` match a group of characters at least `n` times and at most `m` times

Note: This regex will match anything inside the input string. Be careful as you might want to strictly verify that there is nothing before the matched part. See the [answer of Mr. Polywhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75605252/21276039)

Bonus (not mention by the other answer): Matching only this input, but allowing heading and trailing white-spaces `^\s*[1-5](#[1-5]){0,4}\s*$`

Comment: You need anchors. By matching `"1#"`, for example, your regex also matches `"66 cat 6666661#777"`.

Comment: Well, it depends on the requirements of the OP, but yes you're right I'll add them to the answer

Comment: Unfortunately, by adding anchors your answer would become identical to @Mr.Polyswirl's.

Comment: Oops, I didn't scrolled enough to saw his answer, I'll add a note explaining the difference then